# Is there a better way of creating instance objects for a scene in pygame?

Tags: python, oop, pygame

Im looking to create a scene within my game in pygame but i seem to have to render in every single sprite and obstacle individually and as the scene gets larger it gets kind of... repetitive.

```
    self.tree01 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 0, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree02 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 1, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree03 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 2, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree04 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 3, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree05 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 4, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree06 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 5, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree07 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 6, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree08 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 7, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree09 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 8, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree10 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 9, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree11 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 10, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree12 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 11, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree13 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 12, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree14 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 13, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree15 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 14, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree16 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 15, 10, self.player.group)
    self.tree17 = Obstacles(config.tree01, 16, 10, self.player.group)
```

This is how I am currently creating my objects and... that cant be right. My class is here. Is there a way to create all these objects above, with their specific properties in a simplified way? I have thought of creating them in a for loop, but that doesnt give them the individual properties.

```
class Obstacles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image, x, y, player):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.player = player
        self.rect.x = x * config.scale
        self.rect.y = y * config.scale
        self.check_collision = False

        self.rect.topleft = self.rect.x, self.rect.y

        self.groupObs = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.groupObs.add(self)
        self.check_collide()


    def draw(self, screen):
        self.groupObs.draw(screen)
        self.rect.topleft = self.rect.x, self.rect.y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `list()` or a `dict()` to store your properties :

```
self.trees = [Obstacles(config.tree01, x, 10, self.player.group) for x in range(16)]
```

Then you simply access them by index : `self.trees[5]` instead of `self.tree05`

If you don't understand this syntax look up List Comprehension, it's basically a `for` loop but shorter.

Comment: Oh i didn't realise this would work. Thank you so much!